# Website redirects to HTTTP (3 x T)? Only in one specific website and only first time access

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, browser

This one is really weird and I find no answer over the internet (and I am usually good finding solutions online).

I don't know why, but suddenly this website (http://REMOVED) started redirecting to homepage with htttp://REMOVED

But if then we go back and access again, it works flawless!

This website is developed in Wordpress, it always worked without any problems, no updates on any plugins nor wordpress were done. For now this is v4.6.3 (in process to update very soon).

We also have a developing version, which is a copy of this one live and it works flawless...

I honestly cannot understand this one!

Already disabled cache, already substituted temporarily the entire htaccess and nothing seems to work!

This also happens both in PC Safari as well as iPhone Safari.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

Ok, very, very weird! I have tried with Chrome and it seems that everytime I click the first time on a link inside this website, it loads but does not redirect me nor do anything whatsoever... If I click the second time, it shows me the page normally?!?!?! What the... I've been developping for a lot of years and it's the first time I see this happening.

**EDIT 2**

Ok, this is serious! It shows the same error in Edge that shows in Safari and Opera as well, but in Firefox (which is the browser I always use) it's working flawless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found!

Guys, this had to do with WP Super Cache...

I fully unnistalled, eliminated "cache" folder inside "wp-content" and it's working.

ATTENTION: Problem persisted with plugin deactivated, I had to delete that folder.